# "Temporary clone tokens are read-only."

Tags: github

I'm trying to push a change to a repository (public, as URL) that I created. However, I'm getting the following message. Googling doesn't seem to help.

```
> git push origin master
remote: Temporary clone tokens are read-only.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/tackline/Little-Bean.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

The only thing I seem to have done differently is going into the github settings to make the repository public and remove the extra "Features".

What does it mean beyond "403 Forbidden" and how do I fix it?

**Update:** I've checked [Personal settings > Security](https://github.com/settings/security) and two factor authentication is not set up.

However, I find within the [Security log](https://github.com/settings/security-log) section there is a "oauth_authorization.create" followed by failed login attempts.

> tackline – user.failed_login
> Failed to login
> 94.118.116.179 Edmonton, England, United Kingdom 3 days ago
>
> @tackline tackline – oauth_authorization.create
> Created authorization for OAuth application (GitHub Support) with read:org, read:user, user:email scope(s)
> 94.118.116.179 Edmonton, England, United Kingdom 3 days ago
>
> @tackline tackline – user.login
> Logged in
> 94.118.116.179 Edmonton, England, United Kingdom 3 days ago

***Edit:** With @WebManiaK answer I've found the problem. I'll let the bounty run most of its course then add a self-answer to give details.*

Answer (score 5):

Since you mentioned your repository is public and served as URL, I presume you are trying to push using an HTTPS connection. That's fine for most cases, but you may have a better and safer experience by using the [SSH connection](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/which-remote-url-should-i-use#cloning-with-ssh-urls) instead. You'll find how to set that up in GitHub's help center, should you want to.

That said and to come back to your initial question, that might have something to do with Two Factor Authentication. If you activated 2FA on your account, then you have to provide the Git client (namely, your terminal for sending git commands) a [personal access token](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line) instead of your password when authenticating.

Your error message suggests (`403: Forbidden`) you cannot get through that specific process and GitHub is not able to log you in.

I would add that removing extra features such as the Wiki or the issue tracker from a repository **does not have any impact** on the authentication process.

Comment: I found the 2FA setting and made sure I don't have it enabled. I've updated the question with the security logs.

Comment: Using a php code editor, I had to log in using  a GitHub button, I also initially filled in the password, but the action exchanged the token, logging in just supplying the password alone resulted in the error asked in the topic

Answer (score 2):

**"tl";dr:** “Temporary clone tokens are read-only.” is github for your password is wrong.

I reset my password when forced to log in whilst making the repository public. On macOS you can change, and indeed see, yout github password by running "Keychain Access". It's under "github.com".

Comment: I think this is not true. I'm currently having the same problem. When I intentionally type the wrong password I get "remote: Invalid username or password.". Only when I type it in correctly do I get "remote: Temporary clone tokens are read-only."

Comment: In my case my Github actually just wanted me reset my password, since I use a password managers there's no way it was wrong.

Comment: If I use a wrong token I get remote: `Invalid username or password`. This means my token is correct and I get `remote: Temporary clone tokens are read-only.`. Yes I use two-factor-auth ... grrr. Not solved yet.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and in my case, the directory had another repository that I've deleted `.git` directory, but there is a file called `.gitattributes`, deleting it resolved my 403 problem.